# React Redux Toolkit I can't reach state data items when in action

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I want update item in array in redux state but state.data can't find my item but i checked on the redux tool i can see my item so i'm sure. I'd used updateFav action. How can i fix it ?

FavSlice.js

````
import React from "react";

export const FavSlice = createSlice({
  name: "fav",
  initialState: {
    data: [],
  },
  reducers: {
    getFav: (state, action) => {
      return state.data;
    },
    addFav: (state, action) => {
      state.data = [...state.data, action.payload];
    },
    updateFav: (state, action) => {
      var getCart = state.data.find((i) => i.id == action.payload.id);
      getCart = action.payload;
      state.data = [...state.data];
    },
    deleteFav: (state, action) => {
      var findedItem = state.data.indexOf((i) => i.id == action.payload.id);
      state.data.splice(findedItem);
      state.data = [...state.data];
    },
  },
});

export const { getFav, addFav, updateFav, deleteFav } = FavSlice.actions;

export default FavSlice.reducer;```
````

getCart is undefined...

FavList.js

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { updateFav } from "../slices/FavSlice";

function FavList() {
  const fav = useSelector((state) => state.fav.data);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  let body = {
    id: 1,
    name: "deneme",
  };
  console.log(fav);
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {fav.map((item) => (
          <a onClick={() => dispatch(updateFav(body))}>{item.name}</a>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default FavList;
```

**Solved:**

I solved the problem! My items have id's 4 & 5 but i sent id is 1 in fake data so getCart get undefined. I changed id at fake data and my problem was solved.

Thank you to all users who answered.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
updateFav: (state, action) => {
      const findFav = state.data.findIndex((i) => i.id === action.payload.id);
      state[findFav].xxx = action.payload.xxx      // xxx = name, title, url...
}
```

Comment: findFav is undefined… i think state.data doesnt work here. But I can reach items with useselector

Comment: `state.data` is okay, but are you sure an item with that id already exists? have you looked at both the state and the action in the Redux devtools?

Comment: @phry yes im sure I checked on redux dev tools as you said.

Comment: @aaksakal can you show us your update function in your component?

Comment: @MB_ sorry you allright i sent wrong id. I will solve the solution.